# Maximum simultaneous WMI queries?

Tags: wmi

Is there a maximum or recommendation for simultaneous WMI queries to a Server?
I want to known, how many queries I can send at the same time to a system with WS 2008 R2.

Comment: is this a scripting question? might belong on a sister SO board to get a fast answer by system admins

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about number but if server not responding than you can created Multithreaded programme.